# Аналог system(“cls”)

Tags: c++

Подскажете пожалуйста, возможно ли заменить `cpp system(“cls”);`
На что-то такое чтобы не мерцал экран?

Просто если сделать бесконечный цикл, то экран начинает мигать.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void game()
{
    for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y <= 10; y++)
        {
            if(x == 10 and y == 10)
            {
                cout << ‘#’;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ‘ ‘;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    while(true) game();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А Вам просто почистить экран или Вы делаете текстовую игру?

Comment: Суть проста, у меня есть координаты x, y. Далее 2 for по x и y и вывод.

Comment: то есть, Вы делаете постоянное обновление экрана?

Comment: В данном случае есть 2 координаты x, y. И разумеется 2 for чтобы рисовать по 2 осям.

Comment: У меня прописано просто while(true)

Comment: for(int x = 0; x <= xWorld; x++) for(int y = 0; y <= yWorld; y++) if(...) {...} else { cout << ‘ ‘; }

Comment: я знаю, как выглядит for. Вопрос не в том

Comment: Думаю winapi может помочь. `system("cls")` очищает экран, а Вам скорее всего нужно не очищая рисовать поверх новую картинку, т.е. просто переустановить курсор на начало и опять рисовать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842526/update-console-without-flickering-c

Comment: Как вариант - не перерисовывать всю консоль заново, а менять только те символы, которые нужно, устанавливая курсор по координатам. Придется немного изменить логику отрисовки, но это очень сильно забустит производительность. (Актуально, если игра real-time).